# Mouse over , set time out function is not working

Tags: jquery, css

mouse over after two seconds ,but set time out function is not working

js

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.box').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
      marginTop: '-224px',
      height: '300px'
    })
    $(this).find('.rotate-arrow').addClass('rotate');
  });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You have attached the event handler to inside of the setTimeout which essentially means that this will wait 2 seconds before attaching the function to a `mouseover` of the `.box` element.

Unfortunately `$(this)` from the setTimeout function is out of scope so your values were not being read. Luckily you can simply assign `$(this)` to a variable that is *within* the scope of the nested function with which you will be able to access the jquery object as you normally would.

---

**Solution:**

```
$('.box').mouseover(function () {
  var $this = $(this)
  setTimeout(function () {
    $this.animate({ marginTop: '-224px', height: '300px' })
    $this.find('.rotate-arrow').addClass('rotate');
  }, 2000);
});
```

---

**jsFiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/mF46t/

Comment: to optimize the code (avoid repeated jquery element wrap): inside the mouseover function add `var $this = $(this)` and in setTimeout replace `$(this)` with `$this`

Comment: thanks , i tried this ,but it showing cannot read property height